# Auto Complete for city names not working

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, autocomplete

I am trying to get city names in auto complete text box using google places api.  I don't know what is wrong with my code i am not getting city names in my autocomplete text box.

Here is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
        var options = {
            types: ['(cities)'],
            componentRestrictions: { country: "us" }
        };

        var input = document.getElementById('City');
        var places = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);


    });
</script>
```

```html
 <div>

      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.City, new { AllowHtmlAttribute = new { @class = "form-control" } })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.City)
</div>
```

Comment: Mention in your tag that this is `ASP.NET`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Apı key for your googleapis.com reference.

You should be seeing the following error at your console:

> Google Maps API error: MissingKeyMapError

Go to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Use your script reference like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={YOUR_APIKEY};libraries=places&language=en"></script>
```

I tried and it's working fine.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!!